# Какой формат картинок, оптимальнее использовать в web-приложениях

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Какой формат картинок, оптимальнее использовать  в web-приложениях, svg или png?

Я понимаю что svg не везде может загрузиться, просто так, но все таки у svg есть значительные плюсы перед png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного размытый вопрос, Вы имеете ввиду изображения как элементы интерфейса, или изображения вообще? Если первое, то я за svg, особенно учитывая повсеместную адаптивность и распространение highDPI экранов. Из минусов у svg я замечал только: спонтанные проблемы обработки у некоторых браузеров, и размер файлов, без оптимизации, больше чем у png.

Comment: Я рисую svg сам, и размер у меня получился ровно в два раза меньше чем в png. Я думаю что можно еще меньше сделать. Я вас не очень понял. Что именно вы имеете в виду - имеете ввиду изображения как элементы интерфейса, или изображения вообще?

Comment: Я сам не художник, но работаю с изображениями которые мне дают. С иконками, шрифтами в svg меня все устраивает. А вот, например, когда мне приносят какой-нибудь сложный логотип, бывают проблемы с размером. После перевода в растр и оптимизации (optipng, например) размер получается меньше. Хотя, по просьбе, делают тот же самый svg логотип, но в два раза меньше по размеру, оптимизируют как-то.

Comment: Я имел ввиду элементы интерфейса: иконки, шрифты, градиенты, фоны, слайдеры и т.п.. И изображения, как элементы контента: пользовательские картинки, схемы, карты и т.д..